# Error failed to parse xml in androidmanifest.xml

Tags: java, android

I got an error message when opening android studio error failed to parse XML in androidmanifest.xml, ParseError at [row, col]:[14,55]
Message: expected start or end tag

I already try several solutions and still not working

this is my androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.luasdankeliling">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".kubus">
        android:label="Kubus"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.luasdankeliling.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".lingkaran">
        android:label="Lingkaran"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.luasdankeliling.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".segitiga">
        android:label="Segitiga"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.luasdankeliling.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".persegi">
        android:label="Persegi"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.luasdankeliling.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check all your activity tag's closing bracket (except the last one, that is fine). You are not enclosing your ` `android:label` and `android:parentActivityName` attributes inside there respective activity tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 1:**

You are missing `</manifest>` tag at the end, just add `</manifest>`.

**Edit 2 :**

You are not ending the activity tag properly

Your activity is like following

```
<activity android:name=".lingkaran">
    android:label="Lingkaran"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```

But it should be like this

```
<activity android:name=".lingkaran"
         android:label="Lingkaran"
         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
```

Complete manifest should look like following

> ```
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>     <activity android:name=".kubus"
>         android:label="Kubus"
>         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
>             android:value="com.example.luasdankeliling.MainActivity" />
>     </activity>
>     <activity android:name=".lingkaran"
>         android:label="Lingkaran"
>         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
>
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
>             android:value="com.example.luasdankeliling.MainActivity" />
>     </activity>
>     <activity android:name=".segitiga"
>         android:label="Segitiga"
>         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
>             android:value="com.example.luasdankeliling.MainActivity" />
>     </activity>
>     <activity android:name=".persegi"
>         android:label="Persegi"
>         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
>             android:value="com.example.luasdankeliling.MainActivity" />
>     </activity>
>     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

Comment: @imamseptian Updated the answer .

Comment: it works, thanks for the good problem explanation and solution sir

Answer (score 3):

You could find out your self.
Click on "Merged Manifest" tab and on the right pane errors will be shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

no you are not missing manifest tag . how many time you have tried . if you have just tried one time . try again because some time Android Studio behaves like there is a error .

Comment: i already try several time , still the same error message pop up

Comment: have you upgreded gradle version if so try to reformate code